# Stop Python Popen process from inheriting DLLs

Tags: python, dll, popen

I have the following Python code.

```
subprocess.Popen( launchExeFile,
                      creationflags = win32process.DETACHED_PROCESS | subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
                      close_fds = True, shell = True, cwd = workingDir )
```

But what I'm finding is that the process that gets created will inherit some C++ runtime DLLs; specifically, VSRUNTIME140.dll and MSVCP140.dll, and probably others.  How do I stop the spawned process from inheriting these DLLs?  I want the spawned process to load the versions of those DLLs that can be found in the windows/system32 folder.  Does that make sense?  Thanks.

I need to add that the python process is packaged with its own local versions of those DLLs, because I'm using PyInstaller.exe.  My work-around for now is to remove those DLLs from being included by PyInstaller; and maybe that's the best thing to do for now.  It does mean that the C++ redistributable needs to be installed on whatever host wants to run the python program.